# default interface cmd on cisco nexus 5k

Tags: cisco, cli, cisco-nexus

Does anyone know of an equivalent "default interface X" comand for the Cisco Nexus 5000 platform?

```
switch>en  
switch# conf t  
switch#(config)# default interface x
```

-> dead thread here about the topic:
https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10743451/nexus-5k-w413-default-interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually depends on the NX-OS version running on the switch (and hence the switch model). Starting with version 6.0(2)N2(1), the `default interface` command has been added to the nexus world. Compare the [release notes](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/release/notes/6_02/Nexus5500_Release_Notes_6_02.html#pgfId-481452) of this version.

As far as I know, previous versions do not support this or any similar command.

However you won't be able to run NX-OS 6 or later on the 5010 or 5020 platform, it requires the 55xx platform.